# JSON compatibility Issue with Internet Explorer 9

Tags: json, internet-explorer-9

Fetching JSON data is working fine in Google Chrome but in Internet Explorer 9, the browser shows this instead:

> Do you want to open or save the file?

How do I correct this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE9 prompts user on submission of hidden iFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230779/ie9-prompts-user-on-submission-of-hidden-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Does the server set a `Content-Type`-header? Ex.

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

The browser usually knows that `application/json` (like `text/html` etc.) isn't for download, but for the browser itself.

If you don't set it, the broser may think it's just a plain text file and offer it as a download to the user.

Comment: Actually, that content-type *is* the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230779/ie9-prompts-user-on-submission-of-hidden-iframe